# Why does not margin-top less than a specific value work for an inline-block element?

Tags: html, css

In the following code when i specify `margin-top` for `#thirdDiv`, It doesn't work until i give it `36px`.

What is the reason?

```css
#Container {
  border: 15px solid orange;
  width: 350px;
}

#firstDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#secondDiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#thirdDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="firstDiv"> a </div>
  <div id="secondDiv"> b </div>
  <div id="thirdDiv"> c </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might wanna use flexbox instead of inline-block. flexbox is much easier to fiddle around when coding responsive and it's quicker to load in the browser

Comment: because of the line height and vertical align of the parent container - this is a good explanation: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: Basically because b is 32px font size plus 2px border size, it means as the default vertical align is baseline, it will take 15px of margin top on the smaller c before you will notice any difference in position (that is the difference between the font size of c and the parent's line height which hs been stretched to 2em (or around 32px)

Answer (score 1):

Because the child elements of your `Container` element are based on the bottom of that div. If you add `vertical-align: top` to your child elements, any `margin-top` is possible. You can try it out in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqZPXy) where I copied you code and tidied the CSS up a bit. Note that you can choose to only put `vertical-align: top` in your `#thirdDiv` element. This way you can keep the other two divs in their original position.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is padding. The CSS margin properties are used to create space around elements, outside of any defined borders whereas the CSS padding properties are used to generate space around an element's content, inside of any defined borders.

Try the following instead of applying `margin-top` to `#thirdDiv`.

```css
#Container {
 padding-top: 36px;
 border: 15px solid orange;
 width: 350px;
}
#firstDiv {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid red;
 font-size: 1em;
}
#secondDiv {
 border: 1px solid green;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 2em;
}
#thirdDiv {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid pink;
 font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
 <div id="firstDiv"> a </div>
 <div id="secondDiv"> b </div>
 <div id="thirdDiv"> c </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a value for `margin-top` else it won't know how much margin to add.

What were typing for `margin-top` before, `margin-top: ;`?

What is your desired effect?

Comment: I wanted to know the reason for that and why it happen?When i give it 20px it doesn't work

Comment: WIth margin-top of 20px it does work, but the visible change is marginal. If you go onto chrome dev tools and manually add margin-top: 20px to your element, you can increase and decrease it to see what effect it has.